# Load VideoJS with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, video.js

I'm trying to load by AJAX a video working with [VideoJS](http://www.videojs.com/) but I can't manage how to make it work after the AJAX load. I've been reading a lot about this but I couldn't find any solution.

I show you an example. You can check [this link with a working video](http://andreullos.com/test/videojs/video.html).
And [here](http://andreullos.com/test/videojs/ajax.html) I'm trying to load the previous link through an AJAX load.

This is the code I run after the AJAX call. You can check it also in the links I just entered.

```
_V_($('.video-container-large').find('.video-js')).ready(function(){
        var myPlayer = this;
        myPlayer.destroy();
        myPlayer.play();            
    });
    return false;
} );
```

Do you know why VideoJS is not initialized fine? I tried a lot of alternatives without any success, so any help will be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: What is the `exact error` you get

Comment: funny enough, both links are working fine for me :D

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I can't initialize VideoJS correctly. You can check it opening the console in the second link. This is the error: `Uncaught TypeError: The element or ID supplied is not valid. (videojs)`

Comment: @lovetostrike Note that in the second link (the AJAX one) the player is not launched by videoJS, it's only the default HTML5 video player with the ugly control bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument passed to `_V_()` (or `videojs()`) should be an element or an id, not a jquery object. [Use array notation to get the element from the object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/).

```
videojs($('.video-container-large').find('.video-js')[0]).ready(function(){ …
```

Note: `_V_()` was deprecated in video.js 4 and removed in video.js 5. Use `videojs()`.